# TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED locks index on UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transactions

I have observed some unexpected, to me, MYSQL behaviour that I would like to have some feedback on. I have the following two table structure (there is a FKEY relationship between the customer_id fields):

```
tbl_customers
+-------------+------------------+
| customer_id | account_state_id |
+-------------+------------------+
|           1 |                0 |
|           2 |                0 |
|           3 |                0 |
+-------------+------------------+

tbl_customer_records
+-----------+-------------+
| record_id | customer_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |           1 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

In java I select a record from *tbl_customers* using TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level as I want dirty-reads:

```
try(Connection con = DbFactory.getConnection()) {

    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);

    Customer customer = Customer.selectById(con, 1);

    //We preliminary update the customer state to avoid another server attempting the same
    customer.setAccountStateId(1);
    customer.update(con);

    /*Perform long running work here*/

    con.commit();
}
```

If I now attempt to add a customer_record for a customer with id '1' from a different thread with a new connection, I get a lock timeout if the 'long running work' has not yet completed.

It appears that the *'customer.update(con)'* command locks the index on customer_id, preventing any inserts into other tables. This lock is not visible using:

> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

or,

> SHOW OPEN TABLES;

An understanding of why this lock occurs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the actual queries and table structures, including indexes if you want an explanation of why the lock is occurring. Otherwise, improve your logic (why a long process before committing?), and/or increase the lock wait timeout.